Check if subprocess is waiting for screen input
I've been trying to make a script that automatically installs Pi-hole, but I just remembered that Pi-hole asks for some screen inputs (e.g., to ask what upstream DNS provider you want to use). This can be navigated using your arrow keys, but I'm just wondering, is there a way currently where you can check if a subprocess is waiting for a screen input like that?

Well-behaved software gives you noninteractive configuration methods. Don't try to emulate keyboard input -- find the alternate way to configure it (whether that's command-line arguments or environment variables or so forth) and use that. If there is no alternative, that's a feature request.

Anyhow -- you can detect when any file-like object is ready to read data -- that's part of what the select() call (and all its more modern replacements) is for. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html, https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html, etc.

(mind, there's nothing "screen"-related about this -- it's either stdin or it's the TTY, but both of those can be decoupled from any display layer)

...anyhow, in particular for the pi-hole case, --unattended is the flag to run in a mode where no user input is expected.

Thanks! So to install it, I'd use curl -sSL https://install.pi-hole.net | bash --unattended ?

Also, where did you find what flag to use? I looked all over to docs

@CharlesDuffy select() won't tell you if the process at the other end of the pipe is waiting for input. As long as the pipe buffer isn't full, it will say that the pipe is ready for you to write to.

If you want to control an interactive application, use the pexpect library. It can wait for a prompt and then send the response.

As for where --unattended came from -- I read the source code to the installer.

@SmallCoder12, ...realizing I didn't answer your question -- when you're reading a script from a pipe, you need a -s argument to make subsequent arguments be passed through; it'd be curl ... | bash -s --unattended (but with my security hat on, let me make it completely clear that curl | bash is a horrible abomination and anyone who does it gets absolutely no sympathy from me when their machine is recruited to a botnet)

...I've written a longer explanation re: curl | bash at https://security.stackexchange.com/a/213499/56587
